# C++ "error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token"

Tags: c++, syntax

I've been going through a tutorial on game programming using SDL when I encountered this error. I created a class called CApp with the header file below:

```
#ifndef CAPP_H_INCLUDED
#define CAPP_H_INCLUDED

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

class CApp{
    private:
        bool Running;

    public:
        CApp();
        int OnExecute();

        bool OnInit();
        void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);
        void OnLoop();
        void OnRender();
        void OnCleanup();
};

#endif // CAPP_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is the corresponding .cpp file:

```
#include "CApp.h"

CApp::CApp{
    Running = true;
}

int CApp::OnExecute(){
    if(OnInit() == false){
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Event Event;

    while(Running){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)){
            OnEvent(&Event);
        }
        OnLoop();
        OnRender();
    }

    OnCleanup();

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
CApp theApp;

return theApp.OnExecute();
}
```

The error happens on the line in the .cpp file that reads "CApp::CApp{"

I'm fairly new to C++ and even newer to SDL, so any help would be appreciated. I am using CodeBlocks IDE with mingw compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the parentheses that declare the construct to be a method/constructor.

```
CApp::CApp () {
    Running = true;
}
```

Comment: Oh, duh. I can't believe I forgot that. Thank you

Comment: @doelling: It happens to the best of us. You're very welcome.